# mocking injected class method

Tags: python, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

I have a Gateway class that has contains an instance of a Resource class.  I've already done my unit testing on Resource, and to simplify testing, Resource is injected into Gateway as a dependency at initialization:

```
class Gateway:

  def __init__(self, resource):
    self._resource = resource(Master)

  def list_things(self):
    return self._resource.list_resource()
```

Now I'd like write unit test for Gateway to verify that `resource.list_resource()` gets called as a result of calling `gateway.list_things()`.  My best attempt doesn't work:

```
class TestGateway(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_list_things(self):
        mock_resource = Mock()
        g = modbus.gateway.Gateway(mock_resource)
        g.list_things()
        mock_resource.list_resource.assert_called_once()
```

The result:

```
AssertionError: Expected 'list_resource' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the actual use case of the `mock_resource` that you passed into `Gateway` for your test case, the constructor in `Gateway` actually makes a further call to the `resource` argument as a constructor, so that what the test expects is actually emulating the checking of the call against the class method, not the instance method of the `mock_resource`.  Demonstrating this using just the minimum number of statements can be done using the following:

```
>>> mock_resource = Mock()
>>> self_resource = mock_resource('Master')  # emulate Gateway.__init__
>>> self_resource.list_resource()            # emulate Gateway.list_things
<Mock name='mock().list_resource()' id='140441464498496'>
>>> mock_resource.list_resource.assert_called_once()  # test_list_things
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 795, in assert_called_once
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'list_resource' to have been called once. Called 0 times.
>>> self_resource.list_resource.assert_called_once()  # test the _actual_ call
>>>
```

Note that I had assigned `self_resource` to emulate the `self._resource = resource(Master)` statement in the constructor for `Resource`, and the mismatching of the test vs. what is actually executed should now be apparent.

To fix this, the test should check the call like so:

```
    def test_list_things(self):
        mock_resource = Mock()
        g = modbus.gateway.Gateway(mock_resource)
        g.list_things()
        # mock_resource.list_resource.assert_called_once()
        g._resource.list_resource.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: I appreciate your interactive approach to analyzing the problem -- thank you.  Your answer works (and so gets the checkmark), but only tests that `g._resource` gets called.  What I ended up doing was `mock_resource = Mock() ; g._resource = mock_resource ; g.list_things() ; mock_resource.list_resource.assert_called_once()` which gets at the heart of what I mean to test.

Comment: @fearless_fool Oops, I meant to test `g._resource.list_resource`, that was a mistake in the final example - my point still stands on the last line of the first example.  Answer updated nonetheless to reflect my original intention. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also, as an aside, this is exactly why I really dislike using things like `Mock`, because it's too easy to make a mistake that goes under the radar - I rather build them manually - takes more effort, but errors are easier to see.